# Making query with a var

Tags: php, mysql

This is frustrating me a bit. Been working for about an hour on it and I can't seem to find the workaround.

I'm working on a project management site for school, this is the idea: I have one form that has a combobox, this one is filled by a query to a MySql DB, so far so good, in the other webpage

in the second page, I rescue the values I need using the POST method (and it works!). So second page displays the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<b>Codigo Proyecto : </b>" ,$row["codigo_proyecto"] . "<br>"; 
    echo "<b>Nombre Proyecto : </b>" ,$row["nombre_proyecto"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Presupuesto Inicial : </b>" ,$row["presupuesto"] . "<br>";
}
```

That shows the field im getting from the DB, after this there is a buton, which should let me update some fields on the table after a click, code:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar"/>'

if (isset($_POST["guardar"])) {
    $insert="update proyectos_info set presupuesto_final='$_POST[presupuesto_final]' where codigo_proyecto=$_POST[selecciona_proyecto]";
    echo "insert = " .$insert;
    $ejecutar = mysql_query($insert);
}
```

I can't seem to make the variable `$_POST[selecciona_proyecto]` pass to the part where I click the button for the query to complete. I've tried using other variable to store it, using a `fetch_array` only for that field (i.e `$prueba=$row[0]`) it keeps coming back empty, I know it's empty cos I echoed it and this is the output

```
insert = update proyectos_info set presupuesto_final='XX' where codigo_proyecto=
```

Let me know if you need the whole code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). (Also, [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com), ahoy!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will start by saying the mysql_* family of functions are dead. **DO NOT USE THEM**

The following is an excerpt from every PHP doc page featuring a mysql_* function

> Warning
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Presuming your form is something like this.

```
<!-- I suspect that part of your problem is you don't have the form set up -->
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="selecciona_proyecto" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" name="presupuesto_final" value="Guardar"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar"/> 
</form>
```

**Here is how you would have done it back in the days before PDO and mysqli**

```
$presupuesto_final = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['presupuesto_final']);
$codigo_proyecto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selecciona_proyecto']);
$insert = "update proyectos_info 
           set presupuesto_final='$presupuesto_final'
           where codigo_proyecto=$codigo_proyecto";
```

### Here is how you should be doing it.

```
$db = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db_name");
$sql = "update proyectos_info 
       set presupuesto_final = ?
       where codigo_proyecto = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if (!$stmt) return;
$vals = array($_POST['presupuesto_final'], $_POST['selecciona_proyecto']);
$stmt->bind_param('si', $vals);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @solidgear I suspect that part of your problem is that you don't have the form set-up properly. Have a look at the form in my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, that did it...the issue was inside the FORM tags!

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
$insert="update proyectos_info set presupuesto_final='$_POST[presupuesto_final]' where 
codigo_proyecto=$_POST[selecciona_proyecto]";
```

To:

```
$insert="update proyectos_info set presupuesto_final='".$_POST['presupuesto_final']."' where 
codigo_proyecto=".$_POST['selecciona_proyecto'];
```

Will make it work. However, this is really a bad practice as you should be using prepared statements or some other way to mitigate SQL injections.

Please check out some resources on SQL injections and how to prevent them. [Here's a good place to start.](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)

Here are a few code snips from the above article to help get started:

Using straight PHP:

```
$result = pg_query_params( $dbh, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', array($email) );
```

Using mysqli

The MySQL Improved extension handles bound parameters.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('update people set name = ? where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('si',$name,$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: When downvoting, please include an explanation comment so we, those being downvoted, know what to not do again please.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this is the problem, but your missing the quotation marks on:

```
$insert="update proyectos_info set presupuesto_final='$_POST[presupuesto_final]' where 
codigo_proyecto=$_POST[selecciona_proyecto]";
```

So give the $_POST some quotations

```
$insert="update proyectos_info set presupuesto_final='$_POST['presupuesto_final']' where 
codigo_proyecto=$_POST['selecciona_proyecto']";
```